# Set a timer to daily do a API request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have made up my first Home Automation script for Islamic Prayer times. So what I does is that it shows the prayer times on daily basis. The issue is that it does not reset on daily basis. like at 0:00 everyday

So I was wondering like is it possible to set my request at specific time? Or should I just add an restart script for example:

```
import os, sys

def force_restart_script():
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
```

this is my current script

```
import json
import requests

# basics
street = "wallstreet"      # fill in your streetname
housenumber = "5050"          # fill in your housenumber
city = "New York"             # fill in your city
country = "Netherlands"     # fill in your country
angle = "15.0,null,15.0"    # fill in angle

#dont touch
location = street +" "+ housenumber + "," + city +","+ country
url = "https://api.aladhan.com/timingsByAddress?address=" + location + "&method=99&methodSettings=" + angle + ".json"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

r= requests.get(url, headers)
response    = r.content.decode("utf-8")

jsonstring  = json.loads(response)
inner       = jsonstring["data"]

prayer      = inner["timings"]

fajr    = prayer["Fajr"]
dhuhr   = prayer["Dhuhr"]
asr     = prayer["Asr"]
maghrib = prayer["Maghrib"]
isha    = prayer["Isha"]

print(fajr)
print(dhuhr)
print(asr)
print(maghrib)
print(isha)

DOMAIN = 'salat_assistant'

def setup(hass, config):
    hass.states.set('salat.fajr', fajr)
    hass.states.set('salat.dhuhr', dhuhr)
    hass.states.set('salat.asr', asr)
    hass.states.set('salat.maghrib', maghrib)
    hass.states.set('salat.isha', isha)

    return True
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a script I use in my home automation (home assistant).

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, you should look into the "Task Scheduler" program. Just click the windows icon in the bottom left and type "Task Scheduler" in to start it because it comes default with Windows. You can set it to run at various times, for instance and 9:00 PM every day or whenever you log onto the PC.

Comment: alternatively, if on Unix, you could schedule a cron job

Comment: thanks for that! I knew there would be some way on other platforms, but I'm on Windows so I don't know about them.